# Screen snip (win+shift+s) alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to set up my daily requirement tools and features. One of the features I use most is screen snip.

Here are some screenshots that show what I mean by "screen snip":

[image: Screen snip]

[image: rectangular screen snip]

Is there some way I could do the same in Ubuntu just by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and have the screenshot saved to the clipboard (without any external apps if possible)?

Comment: Is this possibly the same as a screenshot?  Please look at [https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html)

Comment: to attempt to get as direct as possible, the combination shift+ctrl+prtscrn will copy an area of the screen to the clipboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is build in in standard Ubuntu. To change the existing shortcuts, open Ubuntu Settings and scroll to 'Keyboard Shortcuts'.  Scroll down to the section "Screenshots". You will find entries to copy the entire screen, the current window or an area you select to the clipboard, as shown below:

[image]

You can change the hotkeys that are assigned by default to the ones you prefer. Click the command, and you will be prompted for the keystrokes that you would like to use as a shortcut.  In my example, Ihave chosen <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

[image]

Pressing the delete symbol next to the command will revert to the default keystrokes.

Comment: The specific one you mentioned will be copied to the clipboard.  By default, those saved to a file go to the `~/Pictures` directory

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+SHIFT+PRINT-SCR copies the selected area screenshot to clipboard

SHIFT+PRINT-SCR save it to pictures folder.

You can access all these shortcuts from settings.
Go to Settings → Keyboard shortcuts

This is for Ubuntu 20.04.2

Answer (score 0):

if the tool is already installed, all you have to do is change the shortcut key; but if the tool is not installed, what is the command? in my case it was not installed.

```
sudo apt install xfce4-screenshooter
```

now the command to snip a rectangular section of the screen selected by holding the left mouse button down and dragging is:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -r
```

press ESC to cancel

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently take different types of screenshots (eg whole desktop, window-only, select area of a window), then the [Screenshot Tool GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1112/screenshot-tool/) may be useful.

This extension adds a menu in the Ubuntu system tray to easily select the type of screenshot:
[image]

There are plenty of useful settings, including auto save location and keyboard shortcuts:

[image]